TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
I am seeing below error after i run 'cds add xsuaa' in project terminal.
Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
at new ProjectReader (/home/user/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@sap/cds-   dk/lib/init/projectReader.js:14:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@sap/cds- dk/lib/init/projectReader.js:8:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/@sap/cds-dk/lib/init/plugin.js:5:18)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)

Please refer to below GitHub repository to recreate the error:
https://github.com/ShaguftaNaaz31/First-CDS/tree/main/e_learning
Thank you in Advance.
Regards,
Shagufta
I have degraded versions of both @sap/cds  and @sap/cds-dk
